# rijndael s-box with an example in simple words

Tags: cryptography, rijndael

All over google and wiki i'm not able to understand the rijndael s-box key scheduling...
Can anyone explain them in simple words and with an clear example????

Comment: You're rotating bits and representing numbers in binary and then polynomial form. It's kind of hard to explain in simple English...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule seems fairly straightforward. Rotate, sbox, xor the first byte with rcon. That's the core of the algorithm, and we use that to build up the key.

Comment: Have you seen the [stick figure guide to AES](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) (skip ahead to Act 3: Details)?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this flash presentation](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1299977086), I've seen it when I was studying the Rijndael Cypher and it was all I needed to understand it, hope you like it too :)

Comment: Your link says `Error 502 : Bad gateway`, can you please give another link ?